# What is the reason for the error reported for the ETS and ARIMA accuracy checks?

Tags: r, arima, ets

The code is as follows.

```
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)

tourism_melb <- tourism %>%
  filter(Region == "Melbourne")
tourism_melb %>%
  group_by(Purpose) %>%
  slice(1)

tourism_melb %>%
  autoplot(Trips)

fit <- tourism_melb %>%
  model(
    ets = ETS(Trips ~ trend("A")),
    arima = ARIMA(Trips)
  )

fit %>%
  accuracy() %>%
  arrange(MASE)
```

Error in accuracy.default(.) :
No accuracy method found for an object of class mdl_dfNo accuracy method found for an object of class tbl_dfNo accuracy method found for an object of class tblNo accuracy method found for an object of class data.frame

What is the reason for the error in the last step?

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that there is no accuracy method defined for the class of object fit. To fix this, you can either define an accuracy method for the class of object fit, or convert the object fit to a class that has an accuracy method defined.

Comment: Is there a specific code, please?

Comment: There is no specific code to fix this error, as the solution will depend on the structure of the object fit. If you can provide more information on the structure of the object fit, I can provide more specific advice on how to fix the error.

Comment: You can see an example from this website(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/vignettes/fable.html) where this is possible
fit %>%
  accuracy() %>%
  arrange(MASE)
The results can be obtained.
However, when I copy the code from the example to my own computer, I get the above error when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be some configuration issue at your computer. I get some output instead of errors when I run your code.I am pasting the output from my console below, when I run your code.

```
> library(fable)
Loading required package: fabletools
> library(tsibble)

Attaching package: ‘tsibble’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, union

> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> 
> tourism_melb <- tourism %>%
+   filter(Region == "Melbourne")
> tourism_melb %>%
+   group_by(Purpose) %>%
+   slice(1)
# A tsibble: 4 x 5 [1Q]
# Key:       Region, State, Purpose [4]
# Groups:    Purpose [4]
  Quarter Region    State    Purpose  Trips
    <qtr> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
1 1998 Q1 Melbourne Victoria Business 405. 
2 1998 Q1 Melbourne Victoria Holiday  428. 
3 1998 Q1 Melbourne Victoria Other     79.9
4 1998 Q1 Melbourne Victoria Visiting 666. 
> 
> tourism_melb %>%
+   autoplot(Trips)
> 
> fit <- tourism_melb %>%
+   model(
+     ets = ETS(Trips ~ trend("A")),
+     arima = ARIMA(Trips)
+   )
> 
> fit %>%
+   accuracy() %>%
+   arrange(MASE)
# A tibble: 8 × 13
  Region    State  Purpose .model .type     ME  RMSE   MAE
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Melbourne Victo… Holiday ets    Trai…  4.67   50.5  37.2
2 Melbourne Victo… Busine… ets    Trai…  3.31   56.4  42.9
3 Melbourne Victo… Busine… arima  Trai…  2.54   58.2  46.0
4 Melbourne Victo… Holiday arima  Trai… -4.64   54.3  41.4
5 Melbourne Victo… Other   arima  Trai… -0.344  21.7  17.0
6 Melbourne Victo… Other   ets    Trai… -0.142  21.7  17.0
7 Melbourne Victo… Visiti… ets    Trai…  8.17   60.9  51.4
8 Melbourne Victo… Visiti… arima  Trai…  6.89   63.1  51.7
# … with 5 more variables: MPE <dbl>, MAPE <dbl>,
#   MASE <dbl>, RMSSE <dbl>, ACF1 <dbl>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: What configuration of the computer do you think it might have to do with?

Comment: Maybe some missing package, or some conflicts in packages.

Comment: Can you suggest some ways to help me identify the problem?

Comment: Have you tried restarting R? In RStudio's Session Menu, there is Restart R. Try to run your code after that. If it still gives error, maybe you can restart your OS.

Comment: I restart R after It can run successfully. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. What is the reason why it works fine after restarting R? And what is the OS you mentioned above?

Comment: This happens when you have some background processes running, which conflict with these functions. Starting a fresh R session gets rid of them.